# Getting error in child view of Expandable listview

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, expandablelistview

I would like to use ExpandableListView in my application. Untill now everything works fine, except the childView. All the childViews are getting matched with each and every single parentView.

```
public class AdTypesAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

Context context;
public LayoutInflater minflater;
ArrayList<Q2_AdTypeList> adTypeList;

public AdTypesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Q2_AdTypeList> adTypeList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.adTypeList = adTypeList;
    context = context;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Context context) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    context = context;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return adTypeList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return adTypeList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return adTypeList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_details_parent_layout,
                null);
    }

    TextView noOfImpressions_textView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.noOfImpressions_textView);
    TextView amount_textView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.amount_textView);
    noOfImpressions_textView.setText(String.valueOf(adTypeList.get(
            groupPosition).getAdvImpression()));
    amount_textView.setText("$"
            + String.valueOf(adTypeList.get(groupPosition).getAdvPrice()));

    // ((TextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView adDesc_textView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_details_child_layout,
                null);
    }
    adDesc_textView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.adDesc_textView);

    adDesc_textView.setText(adTypeList.get(childPosition).getAdvDesc());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Here the adTypeList consists of data for both parent and childview[![
I would like to get exactly what it is in the image. But what I get in my output is that the total number of childview I have is attached to each and every parentview][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr4oS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr4oS.png)

Comment: Hi Parthiban

You using same array for both  (adTypeList)
getGroup &
getChild

Comment: Yes... I'm using the same array for both getGroup and getChild. May I know whether that would be correct???
@Ashraf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `getChildrenCount` should always return 1 based on your data model (each parent has exactly 1 child)

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
    return 1;
}
```

By returning `adTypeList.size()` you basically say that the group at position `groupPosition` has `adTypeList.size()` children.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But When I tried this same value repeats under every parentView. Since there is different value for every childView, Can you please help me a step more?

Comment: My assumption is that in `getChildView` you didn't change `adDesc_textView.setText(adTypeList.get(childPosition).getAdvDesc());` to `adDesc_textView.setText(adTypeList.get(groupPosition).getAdvDesc());`. Based on your view model, you need to grab  the child data from the group position (because as of right now, childPosition it will always be 1)